# Shouldn't KJVO be rejected as a premise of Biblical Hermeneutics?

Tags: discussion

Biblical scholars of every stripe have rejected KJVO as being bigotry, not scholarship. Shouldn't they be denied their Alex Jones/QAnon platform on a site ostensibly about scholarly analysis of these ancient texts? I mean, what does a text that never appeared until 1519 CE have to do with sincere scholarship?

Comment: Just for the reference of your readers what _other_ Greek text (not codex or manuscript but _collated text_) do you propose other than that produced by Erasmus in the 16th century or the Vulgate ? That is to say, if I lived in the year 1520 what text do you propose I should have been using ?

Comment: Is not your stance on this particular matter a form of bigotry itself ? [Oxford English Dictionary](https://www.oed.com/dictionary/bigotry_n?tab=meaning_and_use#20828601) _1.
1616–
The quality or condition of a bigot; obstinate or unreasonable attachment to a belief, practice, faction, etc.; **intolerance**, prejudice._

Comment: This question has failed to distinguish between two schools of thought which is, in itself, an academic failure. Some fanatically represent the KJV as being inspired or close to inspired and would not even countenance its being improved where necessary. Others advocate the Textus Receptus and disagree with its replacement (in 1881) by the Westcott & Hort text, which was heavily loaded in favour of Sinaiticus and Vaticanus (which disagree hugely with one another). Herman Hoskier gave the academic argument that the 4th century recension was flawed and these two codices are examples of this.

Comment: Do you mean the King James Version of the Bible should be rejected "as a premise of Biblical Hermeneutics"? It would be helpful if you edited your question to make it clear whether you mean the King James Verion of the Bible or if you mean the King James Only people.

Comment: I have zero concerns about KJV people, only the KJVO people. This site is ostensibly intrinsically critical about every passage. If any other reading than the KJV is considered wrong for that reason, what kind of discussion can you have them that is objective? It is like having the assumption that a certain preacher is infallible. It is an -ism like the JWs, who insist that whatever the GB says is true, is true and every other opinion is a lie. Ever try to reason with a JW? If you're right but deviate from what they refer to as "The Truth," they don't learn, they just fall silent.

Comment: Ruminator, The "critical" in biblical criticism is not used in a negative sense, but for scientific objective methodology, and KJVo or TR has been rejected for that reason of truth and fact, since the late 20th century. I am hoping for a reformation here where Christianity SE start taking all the questions posted here rather than vise versa, to suit the methodology of dogmatic uneducated people.

Answer (score 6):

KJV-Onlyism is much older that Alex Jones and QAnon, and most KJV-Onlyists wouldn't be associated with either of them (especially outside the USA!) Most Christians do reject KJVOism, but they wouldn't consider it bigotry.

There are several KJV-Only arguments, and they would be appropriate here to varying extents:

1. Those focused on the KJV as a translation. Well arguments that other translations are flawed are definitely on-topic on this site! But they'll have to accept that people will also argue that the KJV has flaws too. If they're not ready for that kind of discussion then this site will be difficult.
2. Those who focus on the Received Text behind the KJV. Several people on this site are proponents of the RT or MT, whether or not they agree with KJVOism. Textual Criticism arguments about varying text branches are of course on-topic.
3. Those who say that the Greek source texts of the KJV, and the KJV itself, are divinely preserved and perfected in ways all other manuscripts and translations are not. This is a theological assertion, and one that doesn't really belong here. But I also doubt it would arise very often on this site.

Comment: Up-voted +1 for discerning the two, very different, schools of thought, the one (KJV 'inspired') being fanatical and the other (4th century recension 'flawed') being academic.

Comment: +1  ... KJVOism should be respectfully argued against when it pops up (very rarely in my experience) but not banned...  ditto for those who insist the Apocrypha on an equal footing with rest of the OT.

Comment: Intended as humor: https://www.reddit.com/media?url=https%3A%2F%2Fi.redd.it%2Fu9ep1juopg211.jpg

Answer (score 2):

What should be rejected on Biblical Hermeneutics is the use of abbreviations that might possibly mislead readers who could end up confused about two categories that are very different. There should be a requirement for any abbreviations used in the main question to be detailed in full in comments following. For example: After putting KJVO at the start, the second time that abbreviation is used, it should read 'King James Version Only (with or without an 'ism' at the end of O).

Likewise, when names of American people, and American organizations or media platforms, are inserted, care should be taken that people from other parts of the world will understand who exactly, and what precisely are meant, and their connection with the abbreviation in the main question.

There happens to be a famous TV personality on British television with the name of Alex Jones, and she (yes, 'she') has got nothing to do with what this question seems to be on about. As for QAnon, I can only guess that 'Anon' is an abbreviation for Anonymous and Q might stand for Question. Whether it is, or isn't, I still have no idea what the OP is on about with those two names.  A few billion people in the world find it intensely irritating that some American people go on-line with the assumption that the whole world ought to know exactly what all their abbreviations and names refer to.

It should also be made clear in questions of this nature that there are people who prefer the King James Version of the Bible to all others, even though they know the KJV is flawed, and not perfect. A lot of them use other translations to do research and to come up with answers here, to help argue their case in a scholarly manner. They are also open about saying they believe that only the autographs of the Bible manuscripts were perfect - not copies of the originals.

The Trinitarian Bible Society is a classic example of such a balanced stance. They only ever promote and print the KJV, not even supporting the New King James Version. They produced a booklet explaining the reason why the NKJV claims were not all sound. They have also stated in print that they know the KJV has flaws in it. Even so, they maintain that it is still the best translation available today. ***But that is not KJVO-ism!***

Whenever people who seem to really dislike support for the KJV lambast the KJVO camp, they need to clearly set the parameters, and stick within them. But trying to tar KJVO supporters with KJV supporters is scholastically misleading, if not downright dishonest when carried too far. It does not matter if they do not intend to tar both groups with the same brush; sloppy use of language and stating generalities without providing specifics that have detailed source references added should have no place on this site.

**My answer to the main question is that KJVO is NOT a premise of Biblical Hermeneutics** - it is a premise of a few individuals who participate here - and they are as entitled to participate as are all others with differing beliefs and views (while being reminded that sloppy use of language and stating generalities without providing specifics with sources fails the expected standards). Yet the main question makes the misleading assumption that KJVO IS a premise of Biblical Hermeneutics!

I suggest rejection of this question as it stands, and that the OP re-submit it with due respect for many people on this site who may find it unclear in its format, and deeply irritating in its assumptions.

Comment: When I google KJVO, it points to the wiki:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King_James_Only_movement and is available in six languages. May I ask if you are irritated because you are KJVO?

Comment: I never Google (on principle). Other search engines are available. The British one that I use responded to KJVO with a link to usekjvonly.org.  I never have been, and confidently state that I never shall be, a King James Version Only advocate, although I believe the KJV is the best translation available today, despite its flaws. I have a line-up of widely varying Bible translations on my desk, ranging from the sublime to the ridiculous. No comment on the latter. I have clearly stated in my answer what irritates me - not you, personally, however, any more than KJVO advocates do.

Comment: So Anne, is it your opinion that you can take any passage from the NKJV (check your British search engine) and put it next to the KJV, the KJV will be completely "God's Word" (whatever that might mean - I consider it the worst possible translation of LOGOS), while in any way the NKJV (or any other translation), varies from the KJV will always be the wrong reading? "Because the KJV is the best translation"?

Comment: @Ruminator  Re. the NKJV: e-mail contact@tbsbibles.org and ask them for their 2008 booklet "The New King James Version - a Critique" by Malcolm H. Watts (15 pages). Ask also for an article in Issue No.624 of The Quarterly Record, July-Sept 2018 entitled "The Twin Doctrines of Scripture" by L.G. Brigden, which says more on the NKJV. No need to ask about my opinion. Remember also that I know the KJV is not always correct, or gives the best rendering. It is not a perfect translation, though I maintain it's better than other ones.

Comment: I was always taught in English class that using the word "better" is essentially meaningless. My concern is that you not bring to BH.se, as many do, "better" and "best" ideas that prevent critical thinking regarding each passage, which you seem to be saying. So no worries, all good.

Comment: Kjvo is indeed the premise for hermeneutics for those who believe it. Read my answer and another answer on the new Topic. This site doesn't have just writing style and source citation as criteria, but it also has a methodological criteria of secular biblical criticism, which disqualifies all those of the dogma, not just Kjvo. I described in detail, it's not practical to ban them on their first post but we must educate, if they persist then ban. I saw CSE also has hermeneutics, they all should be diverted there, instead of hijacking this site. People have forgotten the policy here.

Answer (score -2):

This is a very important topic. From various such topics, it has been proven that banning any particular sect or belief is impossible and impractical, no matter how incorrect it is. It should be all for all.

The purpose of this site is to reduce the jarring gap between intellectual academic knowledge and the church; to develop critical thinking and go beyond CARM website. By educating laymen, we save naive Baptists from turning into Bart Ehrman atheists. This is the function of any academic platform to inculcate education by constant debates from all sides. Many of us may have been KJVO and young earth fanatics while starting here, but slowly we developed ourselves closer towards reason to abandon these viewpoints. Any bizarre area of question should be allowed from *new members*, from palmistry to numerology and meteorology, as long as they are directly biblical text related questions. Free speech and no censorship.

### Where do you draw the line?

The KJVonlysts may have become sophisticated in the academic world, just like Qanon and flat-earthers. Their existence here is not a problem, but the real issue is content quality. I saw this on an [old post](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803):

> **4) This is a university, not a church/synagogue**
>
> We are interested in questions about Biblical texts and the process of
> translating and interpreting them, not absolute truth(s). We want to
> know how things are and have been—what they should be is your concern.
>
> In the university, the Bible (viewed as an academic text of literature
> rather than as 'scripture') is taken up as an object of philological,
> moral, aesthetic, and antiquarian interest.1 The university’s goals
> are "to avoid controversial ideologies, outmoded systems of thought,
> dogmatism, and extreme positions on either end of the theological
> spectrum."2
>
> Imagine being observed by a bunch of professors who know the Bible,
> but don't necessarily believe it (at least not in the same way that
> you do). That is your audience—even if many of us are adherents of a
> religion. In a university setting (such as a rigorously academic
> seminary), truth is often less important than how you arrive at it. A
> quote from the movie Indiana Jones comes to mind:
>
> > Archaeology is the search for fact... not truth. If it's truth you're looking for, Dr. Tyree's philosophy class is right down the
> > hall.
>
> That is not to say that truth isn't important (indeed, those of us who
> adhere to religious beliefs and practices are very concerned about
> truth in our lives)—it's just secondary to scholarship in this
> context. We make the Internet a better place by bringing rigorous
> scholarship to bear on the real questions people have about the
> Biblical texts and the process of understanding them (stopping short
> of the application of these texts).
> **5) We are concerned with hermeneutics, but that doesn't mean we always care 'what you think'**

There are sophisticated versions of KJVO with some rudimentary access to outdated and refuted authors. Normally, we see most fringe dogmatic anti-reasonable people would leave quietly if they don't find positive response, and may find their views easily refuted. However, it is natural that there is a mob formation of certain dogmatic (anti-academic, anti reason) group which would flourish and even begin to rule this site. I suppose this topic is aimed at such kind of members.

The problem is not misinformation or harmful content on which we cannot put a blanket ban, however, if such people who have spent a very long time here and not only they refused to grow, they thrive and generate a spammy bot like behaviour and become the top users, then we can only blame the moderators for failing to control or moderate the flow of content and users. As the quality of a nation is only as good as the judges who implement the constitution, not the constitution itself.

If an inadequate or unqualified user become as influential as Kanye West, he should be banned immediately. The value of the overall content and adherence to the guidelines of this site (academic, critical, original) trumps the free speech right of the individual. The constitution of this site clearly describes an academic spirit which entails Biblical Criticism, as opposed to fanaticism. Even though low quality students are welcomed in a university, but conditions also warrant removing persistent unrepentant rebellious people. Otherwise, you end up letting them giving the control over the board of directors, destroying the very foundations of your university (BHSE).

> **[Biblical criticism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biblical_criticism)** is the use of critical analysis to understand and explain the Bible. During the eighteenth century, when it began as historical-biblical criticism, it was based on two distinguishing characteristics: (1) the scientific concern to avoid **dogma and bias** by applying a neutral, non-sectarian, **reason-based** judgment to the study of the Bible, and (2) the belief that the reconstruction of the historical events behind the texts, as well as the history of how the texts themselves developed, would lead to a correct understanding of the Bible. This sets it apart from earlier, pre-critical methods; from the anti-critical methods of those who oppose criticism-based study; from the post-critical orientation of later scholarship; and from the multiple distinct schools of criticism into which it evolved in the late twentieth and early twenty-first centuries.

Those who persistently demonstrate disregard to reasonable framework cross the line of the site criteria. Especially if they turn into bots or spammers to ***Preach*** their dogmas and faith, becoming the top users. I think the higher mods should take action against those mods who defend such users; the mods should be banned, not just the low quality users. So far, we have only seen some big spam accounts been banned only after they mistakenly exposed their multiple accounts for points. No matter which type of dogmatic user it is (not just KJV), there should be a limit where he should be clearly defined as unacceptable and outside the scope and criteria of the site.

KJVO definitely stands as an anti-reason, dogma and bias, not a neutral open-minded approach that draws from the text. It is a Canon-Dogma bias, not a Bible Critical method of hermeneutics. You will turn into crappy Disney and Netflix if you don't do quality control moderation or don't draw a line. There is still academic value here which makes it distinctive and superior to the unmoderated sites like Christianity and Judaism SE. However, it has been degrading a lot over the years.

Comment: We're not going to ban people for posting things you disagree with. We can suspend people if they persistently post low quality posts, but I'd only consider doing that for people who never try to post justifications for their claims. If people give justifications you think are badly reasoned, well just give them a downvote and move on.

Comment: You mean you can possibly suspend people who post low quality spam which you disagree with. The problem with that is your criteria may be too low, not according to the values of Secular scholarship. Otherwise the site would've have been hijacked by those who persistently violate the principles of secular scholarship of Biblical Criticism. You should raise the issue with ChristianitySE to start allowing Hermeneutics from dogma methodology, to start shifting these people there to improve this site.

Comment: @Michael16 you're always welcome to your own views on the platform, but you'll need to express them in ways that comply with the [Code of Conduct](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/conduct). All users are expected to treat one another with kindness, cooperation and mutual respect. SE is a neutral platform, and is equally welcoming to those of different stances on faith and secularism. Atheists and Theists are equally welcome, and would each do well to learn to value and honour each others' contributions - as indeed they usually do very well on this platform.

Comment: Steve, you are reminding me the rules as if I have violated them or offended anyone? My analogies of the cultural racial background of the Western Christian/secular academic world was merely analogies. If someone finds them offensive, it is their racism. I am not sure, why I am being reminded of code of conduct here. All I did was to explain the concerns of many to reform the site to re-establish the law and order, the issue of the site rules- which obviously do not violate the code of conduct.

Comment: @Michael16 you are speaking very plainly about groups of people whom you are unwilling to treat with kindness, cooperation and mutual respect. It certainly offended other users (obvious from comments here and the other Meta question spawned from it), and even if it hadn't is a perfectly clear CoC breach, in multiple sections of your argument. Please note those I have edited if you are at all unsure.

Comment: Steve, either you misunderstood or deliberately trying to misconstrued my posts and comments. I explained that we should allow the fringe weak positions in the tradition of welcoming and free speech however they should not be welcomed after they persist in their errors which go against the site criteria or principles. This is to implement the rules, not to be unkind. I explained it with analogies of political examples. Implementing rules is not intolerance. My posts expose the error of Marxist relativism in guise of tolerance, which seems constant from your behaviour.

Comment: I'm not expressing any particular sentiments about your overall argument, but rather the specific language that you use to target and degrade those you disagree with. Even the initial comment about a downvote demonstrating 'extremists hijacking the site' was completely uncalled for, and on the surface feels like a backwards way of paying insult to whoever downvoted it, when you've got no idea who they are or what their intentions actually are. You've imputed a lot of undue hostility/intent based on very little information, and then treat your conclusion as if it's the only logical conclusion.