# Where does Stack Exchange-Biblical Hermeneutics draw the line?

Tags: discussion

> Many of us may have been KJVO and young earth fanatics while starting here, but slowly we developed ourselves closer towards reason to abandon childish shit. Any bizarre area of question should be allowed from *new members*, from palmistry to numerology and meteorology, as long as they are directly biblical text related questions. Free speech and no censorship, which are the principles of the supreme White Western civilization.
>
> Where do you draw the line?

The above is [posted on SE-BH Meta](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4085/21426)

Supporting the KJV and supporting Young Earth doctrine is called 'x x x x x '. (see below)

Principles are expressed regarding 'x x x x x x x x x'. (see below)

Reference is also made to 'unmoderated sites like Christianity and Judaism' on Stack Exchange.

---

Yes, indeed.

As a supporter (though not fanatically so) of the KJV and as a supporter (though not fanatically so) of a Young Earth creation, I am interested in knowing -

Where does Stack Exchange - Biblical Hermeneutics draw the line ?

---

EDIT NOTE : Since a Moderator has edited the original answer, in regard to 'a breach of the Code of Conduct', I have also redacted this question.

Comment: It's better to just flag posts you think are offensive.

Comment: I did flag @curiousdannii . . . .  and nothing happened. It is becoming clear where the line is drawn.

Comment: @NigelJ -  Explaining downvotes in comments will help raise community awareness - as well as educate inexperienced users about how to communicate appropriately.

Comment: @DanFefferman Yes, that is one of the fundamental principles of SE.

Comment: @NigelJ ultimately cases of extreme language like this are clear breaches of the Code of Conduct, and should be dealt with accordingly. Flag it and we'll ensure it's handled.

Comment: Thank you @Stevecanhelp . Your edit appreciated, I have also redacted my question, above, accordingly.