# How should we do with uclear answers and answers that appeal to divine inspiration?

Tags: discussion, answers, not-an-answer

While in review queues, found two answers that particularly lead me to write this post, namely

1. https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/50541/27054
2. https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/50505/27054

The 1st answer is unclear what the user is writing. The 2nd is purely opinion based - no research appears to have been done, no linkage to scriptures.

In both of them, I flagged as "Not an Answer" but as

- I'm not entirely sure how this community proceeds in such cases
- The only [similar question](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/583/27054) I found is more focused in answers that really answer the question but then "then proceed to wax poetic on some tangential issue".

One thing concerns me about closing answers of the 2nd kind is that it might remove space for divine inspiration in the author writing the answer.

Comment: Answers have to show their work. Even if God has given someone supernatural insight into a passage, I don't think God will mind if we stay sceptical until they can support their posts with evidence or rational argument.

Comment: @curiousdannii consider posting that as an answer