# Kindness, Collaboration and Mutual Respect

Tags: discussion, moderation, site-philosophy

As Site Moderators, we typically spend *most* of our time doing three things:

1. Cleaning up excessive/non-constructive Comments (we don't enjoy this)
2. Handling Flags raised by site users (do raise a flag if you see something that needs looked at!)
3. Responding to community members and enforcing site policy based on the **Code of Conduct**.

We are occasionally accused of theological bias when taking action - *"why am I being singled out?"*, *"are you silencing my viewpoint?"*, *"are my contributions welcome?"*, but I'd like to assure anybody with any uncertainty here, that serious action is nearly exclusively a result of repeated breaches of the Code of Conduct, which is pretty straightforward:

> The [Code of Conduct](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/conduct) helps us build a community that is rooted in **kindness**, **collaboration**, and **mutual respect**.
>
> Our Expectations:
>
> - If you’re here to get help, make it as easy as possible for others to help you.
> - If you’re here to help others, be patient and welcoming.
> - Be clear and constructive when giving feedback, and be open when receiving it.
> - Be inclusive and respectful.
>
> Unacceptable Behaviour:
>
> - No subtle put-downs or unfriendly language.
> - No name-calling or personal attacks.
> - No bigotry.
> - No harassment.

All community members are strongly encouraged to Flag any contributions which do not adhere to these standards.

### These are not secular values

The Biblical Hermeneutics Stack Exchange [is not a Christian Site](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/441/friends-we-are-not-christian?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C43.9591), but in these matters the SE CoC marries up very neatly with traditional Judeo-Christian values. It wouldn't really be any different in this way if it was a Christian site. In many ways this makes it fairly straightforward to moderate, and I don't personally think of it any differently than I would think of the standards for interaction on a Christian site. We could just as easily be quoting scripture on any of these points:

- *"You have heard that it was said, 'You shall love your neighbour and hate your enemy'. But I say to you, **Love your enemies** and pray for those who persecute you"* Matthew 5:43-48
- *"Always be prepared to give an answer to everyone who asks you to give the reason for the hope that you have. But do this with **gentleness and respect**"* 1 Peter 3:15
- *“Therefore **be merciful,** just as your Father also is merciful.”* Luke 6:36.
- *“He has shown you, O man, what is good; and what does the Lord require of you but to do justly, to **love mercy,** and to **walk humbly** with your God?”* Micah 6:8
- *“**Blessed are the merciful,** for they shall obtain mercy.”* Matthew 5:7.
- *“**Judge not, that you be not judged**... whatever you want men to do to you, do also to them, for this is the Law and the Prophets.”* Matthew 7:1,12
- *“For judgment is without mercy to the one who has shown no mercy. **Mercy triumphs over judgment**.”* James 2:13

No matter how strongly you disagree with somebody, there's absolutely no good reason - religious or otherwise - that you can't disagree, object or correct another community member in a way that is kind, respectful and inclusive. Beyond that, if content is objectionable or false, give it a Downvote. Flag it, if appropriate. Vote to Close, or Vote to Delete, if appropriate.

In my experience, it is absolutely crucial to approach every disagreement with the humble awareness that *we might be wrong* - if we can't disagree in a way that is kind and respectful, there's basically no point in disagreeing at all, because the person we're talking to will just take offense, ignore what we've said, and go on with their day without a second thought. Nobody wins, and the site content quality certainly loses.

### Biblical Hermeneutics SE Community - You are Awesome

Due to these synergies we see admirable, excellent and praiseworthy interactions on the platform every day, where users with yawning chasms between their viewpoints treat each other with kindness, humility and respect. We see comment trails every day which exemplify Judeo-Christian values in how community members treat each other, and that's awesome.

As an active contributor to the site, *thank you* - thank you so much for every comment you chose not to post, or deleted, because it was unkind, or disrespectful. Thank you for every time you've shown somebody else the benefit of the doubt, especially if you have strong disagreements with their theology, hermeneutical principles or anything else. Thank you for every time you've read an oppositional comment and found something true and constructive in it, and avoided an unnecessary argument. We know how tough it is, so thanks for everything you've done and continue to do!

### We aspire to follow your example, and to model those same exemplary behaviours

I hope you're encouraged to know that we aspire to the same standard as a Site Moderation Team - though we take the standards seriously, we always err on the side of giving users the benefit of the doubt. We look for positive contributions, positive behaviours, positive patterns, signs of reform, signs of hope, and don't judge exclusively on people's worst moments (because in our worst moments, we can be just as bad!)

If you could peek into our Moderator chat, you'd see us mostly chatting about site tools and giving each other help and advice, and whenever it comes to questions of discipline, we make sure we *slow down* and *act together*. Where we have been directly involved with a user or situation, we usually *hand off* any key decisions or interventions to others who haven't, and intercede with one another for community members, looking to see the best in each member, as far as is possible with us.

If anything, this typically causes us to be a bit over-slow with site discipline, but when we make a decision there is always abundant evidence for doing so - many flags, many instances and quotes to draw upon, and our penalties are usually on the side of caution/generosity. We recently had a Community Moderator stop by as a result of a disciplinary decision on the site, who analysed all of our correspondence and remarked that they were *"astounded at the grace you all showed this user"* - and so from that rare peek behind the scenes hopefully you can rest assured that we do our best to 'go the extra mile' for you as a community.

### Please do use Flags, Upvotes, Downvotes and Vote to Close/Delete

The highest tenet of our Moderation philosophy is to *do as little as possible*, and allow the community to take care of itself. But we need everybody's help to do that - so please use all the tools you have earned!

- **Upvote** helpful content (regardless of its viewpoint) - this is important!
- **Downvote** unhelpful content (regardless of its viewpoint) - this is equally important!
- **Vote to Close** Questions which don't adhere to the site scope (we honestly can't Vote to Close without instantly Closing a Question, and we would far rather the site makes such decisions communally)
- **Vote to Reopen** Questions which have been updated to adhere to the scope.
- **Vote to Delete** Answers which are low quality
- Raise as many **flags** as you can to ensure that questionable content gets the appropriate intervention. We'd always rather a flag got raised unnecessarily than objectionable content went unnoticed.
- Leave **Comments** appropriately, particularly explaining why you have cast any kind of negative vote against some content, and giving the poster the opportunity to understand the feedback and address the concern. Help people understand what they're doing wrong.

All these things help the site to tick along more smoothly, avoid the need for Moderator intervention, and ultimately result in higher quality content across the site, which is something we all want to see! And in all these things, model the **Code of Conduct** as best you can - there's no constructive feedback in this world that can't and shouldn't be given in a kind and respectful way.

### In Closing - Personal Reflection

That's the end of what I can say fairly for the team. Speaking personally, as a Christian who was previously an atheist and holds a degree in cross-cultural studies, I **love** a diversity of viewpoints, and so I love the democracy of the neutral platform that is Stack Exchange. I love that we eagerly added a non-Trinitarian moderator to the team to strengthen our neutrality, and we certainly hope to add others in the future.

To me, the principles of this platform lend themselves very well to our specific discipline of hermeneutics, where all viewpoints are welcome and can be articulated fairly, and so long as they all follow the model of **kindness, collaboration and mutual respect** everything else is fair game. As a Moderator, I aspire to follow the example set forth for me by Jesus:

> Romans 5:10-11
>
> For if, while we were God’s enemies, we were reconciled to him through the death of his Son, how much more, having been reconciled, shall we be saved through his life! Not only is this so, but we also boast in God through our Lord Jesus Christ, through whom we have now received reconciliation.

Two decades ago I was the angry atheist who hated God, I have partaken in this *reconciliation*, and so it is my joy to actively pay that forward and be a participant in *reconciliation* to others every day. He loved me and showed immense mercy and kindness when I hated him, and so that's what I should aim to do for others.

> 2 Corinthians 5:18-19
>
> "All this is from God, who reconciled us to himself through Christ and gave us the **ministry of reconciliation**: that God was reconciling the world to himself in Christ, not counting people’s sins against them. And he has committed to us the message of reconciliation."

Thanks again to the whole community, the other Site Moderators and Community Moderators for being wonderful co-labourers in these endeavours on the Biblical Hermeneutics Stack Exchange. And have a great day.