# We need to downvote more

Tags: discussion, voting

**DISCLAIMER:** Allow me to begin with a caveat: SE users are free to vote however they please. The only 'official' criteria for voting on questions are:

- It shows research effort
- It is useful
- It is clear

And the only 'official' criterion for voting on answers is:

- It is useful

These are very subjective. I'm proposing that quite a bit of content doesn't meet these criteria and *should* be downvoted, especially that posted by new users to the site. With that said, **users are free to vote however they please.** This post is an attempt to persuade you to change your voting habits (i.e. downvote more), but this should be taken as one user's argument to do so, not as any sort of official guidance. Feel free to voice dissent (or agreement!) in answers to this post.

---

I recently proposed a new site on the SE network, and I was struck by this reminder:

[image: Sites for Experts]

I sometimes wonder how often we lower the bar in the name of being welcoming, despite [repeated exhortations](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7/423) to do otherwise. At the same time, we need to remain viable—but I don't believe that we should sacrifice quality for quantity.

[I've addressed catering to experts before](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1019/423), but this is an encouragement towards specific action. I believe we need to see more downvotes here at BH.SE. We're doing a much better job than we used to with voting in general, and that's awesome (good job)!

However, the system works best when votes help filter the signal:noise ratio. I think there are some reasons why folks here tend to DV less than on other sites (based solely on my subjective judgment):

- Many religious practitioners or otherwise nice people feel it is mean or harsh to DV, especially downvoting new users.
- Some users believe that downvoting should be reserved only for heinous or offensive content, and not for substandard answers that make an attempt.
- Some users believe that a DV should be a last resort, to be done only after attempting to communicate with the user or otherwise improve the content.
- Some are simply afraid to lose the reputation point(s).

I'd like to address each of these objections to downvoting:

### Downvoting is too harsh (or mean), especially when it's a new user

Suppose you're a new user and you ask a question or post an answer and get several upvotes. What's your initial impression? "Hey, my content is welcome here and people like it." Then all of a sudden, a few questions and/or answers later, you start getting more critical feedback and even attract a few downvotes. Now what are you thinking? "What has changed? Why is my content no longer acceptable?" Consistency is key here. It's important to uphold our standards and expectations right from the get-go. This will be slightly foreign to most religious practitioners—everyone will need a little adjustment. It's best to initiate this feedback *immediately.*

Concerning downvotes being harsh (or mean), it isn't personal (and votes are anonymous). Some types of content are more helpful than others. If all posts are upvoted despite varying levels of quality, the message is that they are all equally useful. And that's simply often not the case. Voting is not a popularity contest, it's a metric for evaluating content.

### Downvoting should be reserved only for heinous or offensive content

In a neighborhood filled with homes, one house with a broken window is hardly an issue. But once you have several, trespasses will likely increase and bigger problems will begin occurring. [The broken windows theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broken_windows_theory) is "a criminological theory of the norm-setting and signaling effect of urban disorder and vandalism on additional crime and anti-social behavior. The theory states that maintaining and monitoring urban environments in a well-ordered condition may stop further vandalism and escalation into more serious crime."

A similar principle applies here: upvoting lots of mediocre, sub par content alongside expert-level content puts them on a level playing field and equally encourages both. This eventually causes the less useful content to increase, drowning out the expert material. We're not there yet, but we flirt with this path too often. Downvoting is a way of saying, this is *not* useful, we're looking for more. Upvotes should not be used merely as a reward for effort—the content should be of sufficient quality.

### Downvoting should be a last resort

In theory, this isn't a bad approach. But in practice, what it usually translates to is **inaction**. I've said these things myself:

- "I won't downvote this now, instead I'll comment or edit then wait to see if the user improves or not."
- "I'm too busy to offer constructive feedback right now, so instead I'll do nothing—hopefully someone else will say something."

The problem is that we often forget to ever return to these posts, despite these users often never improving (many never even register their accounts). Or no one deals with the problem (this community is moderated by *you*—moderators are here to handle the exceptions—usually indicated by flags). **The time to downvote sub par content is immediately**. You can always *reverse* your downvote later if the user edits their post.

### Downvoting isn't free

It's true that there is a one-point reputation deduction when you downvote *answers*. But downvoting questions *is free*! [Jeff Atwood explains:](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/03/the-value-of-downvoting-or-how-hacker-news-gets-it-wrong/)

> Downvotes give you the critically important ability to **distinguish
>   between the good, the bad, and the ugly**. Without downvotes, how can
>   you possibly tell the difference between a post that is harmless but
>   uninteresting, and one that is actually wrong or harmful? Sure, it
>   stings a bit to get downvoted. I’ve been downvoted myself on Stack
>   Overflow. And each time, it makes me pause. But that’s *good*! That’s
>   *necessary*! You have to believe there are potential consequences for every post you make — both good and bad. This is how things work on
>   real playgrounds; why would we expect our web playgrounds to be any
>   different?
>
> The idea of a world where nobody can be downvoted strikes me as more
>   than a little utopian. Is it realistic for users to expect to post in
>   an environment where there are no penalties at all, no way for their
>   peers to express disapproval or disagreement with their post? When you
>   can’t leave a quiet, anonymous downvote, you’re more likely to post a
>   snarky reply to express your displeasure. That’s why **disallowing
>   downvotes is actively harmful to community**.
>
> The problem isn’t downvotes, per se, but encouraging *responsible*
>   downvoting. That’s why on Stack Overflow, we do it this way:
>
> - Upvotes add **10** reputation to the post author
> - Downvotes remove **2** reputation from the post author, *and **1** from your reputation*
>
> The trick here is that downvotes are mostly informational. The cost of
>   a downvote to the users’ reputation (or karma in Slashdot/Reddit
>   parlance) is quite low. It would take a whopping 5 downvotes to equal
>   the effect of a single upvote. And, on top of that, downvotes cost you
>   a tiny bit of reputation. The net effect is that you have to feel very
>   strongly about something to downvote it. Downvotes are serious
>   business, and not to be cast lightly. We designed our system around
>   that maxim....
>
> An environment where nobody has to feel the sting of a downvote is a
>   laudable goal, and it’s certainly easy to implement. But is it real?
>   Is it *honest*? **The lack of a downvote removes far too much of the
>   critical community feedback loop from the system.** And in the longer
>   term, that will do more to tear down your community than build it up.

I hope this has helped you realize that we need to downvote substandard content more. Content is not useful if it doesn't meet [our guidelines](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/803/423). There are already websites for religious practitioners of Christianity and Judaism. We must cater to experts in biblical studies.

Comment: have you mentioned that DVing a question is free?

Comment: @JackDouglas - took me a while to discover that. It was quite liberating. :)

Comment: @JackDouglas I actually didn't know that! I learned something new today! I just updated the post, thanks :)

Comment: I don't know how seriously to treat their desire for 'experts', but more voting in general would be good.

Comment: @curiousdannii indeed, there is also a lot of stuff that deserves way more *upvotes* as well!

Comment: Dan have you considered posting an "we need to upvote more"? I think it would be beneficial, as there are numerous posted questions that meet the criteria but which no one cares to upvote. And upvoting is really free, so I cannot understand why people here are hesitant to upvote when they clearly deserves it. People need to understand that an upvote is not a certificate of excellence, it is just a way of saying "this question is worthy to be asked".

Comment: @Bach an upvote in answers indicates the answer is helpful, for questions I upvote when o think a question is interesting. I don’t upvote stuff that won’t attract experts, particularly when it shows the OP has not read even basic books or done any research on their own. I make some exceptions where such research is prohibitive, such as when it is asking about ancient languages. But that’s just me. I’m just one dude. Feel free to post your own appeal for upvotes.

Comment: @Dan I agree that questions that show lack of research should not be upvoted. But it happens a lot (and I've seen it multiple times) that great questions simply do not get the upvotes they deserve. I see 20 views but no upvotes. I feel like, "guys, at least dowvote if not upvote, do something!" There is no question that users here are reluctant to upvote, and I think we need to raise awareness.

Comment: @Bach it could just be low participation overall. What is one of the questions you think should have more upvotes (out of curiosity)?

Comment: @dan see for example this https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/6209/was-the-song-of-solomon-originally-a-series-of-unconnected-love-poems... 107 views and not a single upvote!

Comment: @Bach keep in mind not all views are users who can vote. That is how many people on the Internet viewed it.

Comment: @Dan actually it has been upvoted once, but was mysteriously downvoted and has been that way since

Comment: @Dan I reckon most of the viewers were users who were able to vote but didn't.

Comment: @Bach for that question, I would not vote at all (and haven't). It's not so bad to warrant a downvote, but it also shows a lack of research effort and seems a bit broad. Many study bibles address this in their introduction to the book. If the OP had read such an introduction then asked a more specific question about a specific passage, I'd have upvoted. But that's just me. I can't comment on why others vote the way they do. In my mind, the question does not attract experts. It's a basic question that is a bit broad and shows little to no research effort.

Comment: @Bach [nope](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/36728/166644) - in fact, most views probably are *not* users of the site - they often find it through a Google search.

Comment: @Dan I guess other viewers feel the same way, but I don't. It's not like this question can be easily solved by looking it up in a commentary, so in my opinion this and other similar questions should be upvoted more easily.

Comment: @Bach I just flipped open the *Jewish Study Bible* and found: "The compositional history and origin of the Song of Songs remain matters of debate. Most commentators agree that the book is a collection of poetic units which are linked by theme, language, and style...." And it goes on. [You can even read free online commentaries about this](https://archive.org/stream/songofsongstrfro00ginsuoft#page/124/mode/2up) (albeit a bit dated, but still a great starting point that would show some initial research effort on the part of the OP).

Comment: An *evangelical* commentary, intent on taking the text at face value as the words of Solomon inspired by God, may not address these things. But any decent scholarly one will. And as I linked to in my previous comment, such commentaries can be found for free online.

Comment: @Dan I believe the OP only asked after she did some rudimentary research. As you quote from the JSB, this still remains a matter of debate, so the OP wanted hear other users opinion on the matter. Is that so terrible? An example of a question that shows virtually no effort of research on the part of the OP is this one https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/33303/in-exodus-222-when-may-the-intruder-be-killed indeed i did not upvote

Comment: @Bach s/he should cite what s/he has read then ask a more specific question in my opinion. But that's just my opinion: I did not downvote that question, it isn't bad. Just not upvote-worthy in my opinion.

Comment: @Bach that's another one I would simply not vote on either. It's an OK question, so no DV. But certainly also no upvote from me.

Comment: what about mine here? https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/32921/is-the-term-הֻצַב-the-name-of-an-assyrian-princess-mistress-in-nahum-27 it did not attract so many viewers to begin with, but only one upvote from 30 views is still meager

Comment: @Bach great question. I just upvoted

Comment: @Bach again, most views are *not* users of this site.

Comment: @Dan thanks. I think you get the idea. In any case, I think that strict hermeneutical questions do not get much attention here. If the title is not too catchy or ostentatious it will not attract to many views.

Comment: @Bach part of the issue is the signal-to-noise ratio, which is precisely what downvoting (and upvoting) improves. I frequently come and get so disgusted with garbage in the first few questions/answers I see I just end up leaving. I know for a fact I'm not alone in this. If more users downvoted stuff that was not going to attract experts and upvoted great stuff, that would help a lot. But people here don't downvote enough compared to other SE sites.

Comment: That is, if the user is not too popular. For example this https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/33349/why-does-nehemiah-say-it-was-still-the-twentieth-year-in-nehemiah-2 attracted more than 1200 views in one day because a popular user answered it

Comment: @Dan I wholly agree with your point. I gotta run now.

Comment: @Bach but be sure to read the screenshot in this post, which is directly from SE giving guidance on attracting users. I would argue that folks with nothing but their Bible who happen to attend religious services are not experts, and not necessarily the people we want to attract (at least we don't want the majority of *answers* to come from these folks if they have not read considerably about the historical, linguistic, and literary context of specific biblical texts). I'm a novice myself but I read constantly.

Comment: Also check out: [A helpful flowchart for asking questions on BH.SE](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/867/423)

Comment: See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/02/22/are-some-questions-too-simple/): "The key distinction to make here, in my mind, is that **all questions are ultimately in service of the people *answering* them.** That is the audience you need to satisfy if you want to have any hope of creating and sustaining a community of peers learning from each other. The minimum bar for a question is not “is this on-topic?”, but rather “is this *somewhat interesting* and on-topic?”."

Comment: *We need to downvote more* - Your wish is my command ! Now, is there anything else you'd like me to do ?

Answer (score 10):

At the risk of challenging some well established SOP's, I have found the following:

1) "***Who screens these calls, anyway?***"(From CarTalk)

At the initial input level we are reminding 1st time and new users to "*Read Site Directives*". Coming from a "Forum" background(which way outnumber SE environs) is a difficult transition. This requires some patience and prudence(which people from Chicago aren't noted for) to re-direct their energies from verbal spews to thoughtful, insightful, critiqued answers. You don't get there overnight. Constructive criticism is helpful(I always post a comment on a negative vote). Some people get it, sharpen up their responses and deliver worthwhile answers. Others just look for another outlet to spew verbage; most of those never respond again.

2) **Who are the Experts, anyway?**

It has been my contention from Day 1 that the Academics(those that do this stuff for a living) aren't here. There may be a couple, but most of them have Peer Reviews, papers to write for various projects and really don't have the time or inclination to answer the germane questions posted here; much less ask a question. This site is more about Enthusiasts, who may have attended(or graduated) from bible school, divinity or other programs, who are bored out of their minds with JAVA or C++(what they do for a living) and are genuinely interested in discerning scriptural passages, and writing about their conclusions. Even the student traffic is small, compared to the dopes(like myself) who have a bible and know how to read. We get 'better' because we like what we're doing and don't have someone holding a gun(or a paycheck) over our heads to get it done.

3) **Why do I DV?**

I admit I downvote rarely. I also admit I comment frequently. Why?

There is no "win" or "lose" here; who's keeping score? It's how you respond that counts, and a UV or DV isn't the best indication of what a Good Answer brings. I used to DV answers that I fundamentally disagreed with, now I don't; in fact I have UV'd numerous answers that I have serious reservations with, why?

A thoughtful, insightful, critiqued answer doesn't always come from my particular persuasion. I may challenge the presuppositions that such an answer may be based on, but can applaud the effort one takes in arriving at such a conclusion. If I can say, "You have a point, based on your treatment of "X", but what about "Y"?", chances are they are going to get an UV.

What I reserve DV's for are answers like, "That's my opinion, so there." Or, after counseling someone to make an adjustment, they continue on in circular reasoning, supporting 1 false conclusion after another without regard for accuracy. DV to extinction is the preferred weapon of choice.

4) **What about 'meh' answers?**

'Meh' answers are answers most likely given without a lot of clarity and preparation; they answer the question but are short on specifics or insight. Yeah, I could DV these but I would wake up with cold sweats with visions of Mrs. Pruneface and her horned-rim glasses saying,"Don't you know what dangling a participle is?" "Meh" answers are just that, attempts by individuals to post an answer that somehow got sidetracked(maybe the boss heard your keyboard rattle and thought you were cranking out code). I leave them alone, and sleep without feeling the saliva spray from Mrs. Pruneface.

In Summary, these items capture the majority of reasons why I do(or don't) DV.

Comment: I *upvoted* this post :P -- you are indeed free to vote as you please. Downvoting the 'That's my opinion, so there' posts and the circular reasoning posts is excellent. My encouragement is primarily targeting folks who don't DV at all or very minimally and inconsistently.

Answer (score 2):

### We Need to Upvote More Too

Things may have changed since the OP question was written, and I have no problem with downvoting for poor quality. What I do have a problem with is downvoting because of theological differences.

I see many well researched, useful answers that get few if any upvotes. This is particularly true for posts in the last few years. Do people think they should only upvote an answer if it fits with their denominational or individual theology? It seems to me that even if I disagree with the theological implications of a well constructed answer or question, I should upvote it as useful, and also to reward the researcher for their effort.

Comment: I’m the OP and I upvoted this post :D

Comment: With that said, I’ll generally downvote any answer that is theological if it does not respect the question’s mode of discourse. See https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/886/423 . Too many answers jump straight to theology when the question is, e.g., linguistic or historical in nature, and I will DV those answers regardless of what theological perspective they espouse because it’s the wrong mode of discourse. This happens a lot here IMO.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be great to have a reverse ranking approach that could be used for those who would like to explore questions that were voted down due to some obscure technical reason, or because some didn't like the questions because they were not worthy of the same level of usefulness - e.g. the meaning of some of the symbolism in the Book of Revelation. I suspect there are also those that like to upvote, or close a question, simply on the basis of how much it fits or departs with their theological views.

For example, my post [here](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/78999/44608) mentioning the analysis of Bart E. was given a negative vote with an attempt to have it migrated. I was fine with that. But it seems redundant to have two sites, even if BH gets more visitors.