# Should my answer have been deleted by a moderator?

Tags: discussion

Susan commented concerning [my answer here](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/35660/10955):

> *This does not appear to address the question. It was flagged for deletion for that reason. I agree with the flag given that the only mention of the question at hand is to disregard it ("Regardless of the struggle to understand how the nakedness of the priests might have been exposed...")*

If Susan and the person who flagged my answer for deletion had have read it free of bias against my EPV interlinear, then they would have noticed this in my answer:

> Since there is no mention of steps in the construction of the Tabernacle, this cautionary instruction was likely due to the nature of the construction of the altar and the careless practices of the priests of other nations in their worship of gods of silver and gold (Exodus 20:23).

Surely it is worthy of note that the steps referred to in Exodus 20:26 had nothing to do with the construction of the Tabernacle or the altar, but that they were simply a matter of convenience for the priests. Also that the prohibition was possibly linked to Exodus 20:23 in regard to someone's (the LORD's, Moses') observation of the "*careless practices*" of the priests of other nations, i.e. that they had no concern about dignity in their service to their gods.

I also said this:

> Given these dimensions, it would be tempting for the priests to want to elevate themselves with steps to reach all areas upon the altar without stretching. However, Exodus 20:26 forbids them to do so.

Did I really need to mention that in their stretching to reach objects upon the altar that their garments might be lifted, thus exposing their buttocks to whomever might be observing their activity. If someone thought that this needed to be explicitly mentioned, then surely that is what comments are for.

I am under no allusions that my question here will be met with any reasonableness. However, let it be known that I have no intention of not continuing to develop and use the EPV in my answers. So, downvote/delete to your hearts content.

Comment: Not sure how to put a link in the question title.

Comment: I don't think you can. Why do you need a link in the title? You can just put the link in the actual question.

Comment: In regard to your last paragraph -- I'm actually happy to undelete the answer if there's a consensus here that it should be, which is why the part of my comment  you didn't quote also suggested posting here if you disagree. When posts are flagged NAA and a quick read through the answer doesn't convince me otherwise, I don't spend that much time looking for more subtle aspects that may constitute an answer, but I have no  problem reconsidering.  (Note that I also suggested editing to clarify the answer and then flagging for un-deletion, which I would have also considered.)

Comment: @Susan Why not communicate your intent via a comment? I would have thought giving consideration to deleting a post would demand from you a greater scrutiny of the answer than just "*a quick read through*". This question received two upvotes before anyone decided to downvote. If history is any indicator, it will only be a matter of time before it reaches the negatives. You just keep doing what gives you a buzz, Susan, and I'll deal with it. LOL, I just noticed Jack's post has also been downvoted.

Comment: I think stuff here is generally not as personal as you seem to think. This decision wasn't. Moderators are volunteers who have to get through the flags. Neither perfection nor detailed scrutiny of every answer are required; being willing to be confronted and corrected by the community is. As I've said from the time I handled the flag and commented, I'm happy to re-consider (and move on!).

Comment: @Susan I would agree with an "undelete" move on your part as well.

Comment: @ScottS The question was closed and the OP [re-posted the answer](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/35884/3555) on a different question. I undeleted the first anyway though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Who flagged my answer for deletion?

It doesn't matter who flagged your answer — please consider changing the title of your question to something like "should my answer have been deleted by a moderator?"

Flagging, like voting, is mostly private and needs to stay that way. Moderator decisions are public and this is the correct place to question them so I've upvoted your question here despite the title.

> Did I really need to mention that in their stretching to reach objects upon the altar that their garments might be lifted, thus exposing their buttocks to whomever might be observing their activity. If someone thought that this needed to be explicitly mentioned, then surely that is what comments are for.

I don't think so — having read your answer carefully, had it not been deleted I would consider upvoting it, as it is useful and mostly builds from the question. I wouldn't have thought it was a candidate for mod-deletion. If it had been deleted by the community I'd vote to undelete, but that isn't possible now.

I hope the moderators will reconsider the decision to delete your answer. As not everyone will be able to see it now here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your input, Jack.

Comment: Regarding `If it had been deleted by the community...` -- just to clarify (not because I think you were implying otherwise), I think I don't have the option when handling a flag to defer to the community, correct? That sort of thing (if I understand correctly) can only happen if the flagger has adequate rep and chooses to VTD rather than flag as NAA.? It's unfortunate; contrary to the implication of OP's comments above, I would have loved to let others decide that one. I don't see that happen much on this site, I presume because of the rep requirements.

Comment: Oh, right, I [already wrote that rant](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3191/3555).

Comment: @Susan you don't have the option I'm afraid. 'Normal' users like me need 2000 to VtD questions and 4000 to VtD answers (with score -1 or less). I already upvoted your 2015 post, I couldn't agree with you more!

Comment: @enegue - It seems like everyone is OK with undeleting this post, but that isn't possible. Perhaps you can re-post the same answer as a work-around?

Comment: @JamesShewey As it happens the author whose question I answered asked two almost identical questions on the same day. When I discovered the second question yesterday, I posted my answer [there](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/35622/10955) -- with a suitably modified conclusion.